# iPhone app "rejecting" incoming calls?

Tags: iphone

A client of mine just informed me that, while using the app I am developing for them, they received an incoming call, but it did not bring up an alert on the iPhone. Instead, the person making the call heard a message that the user's service was temporarily unavailable.

If we put aside for a moment the possibility that either the person making the call did not have a signal to make a call, or that my client did not have a signal to receive a call, is there any conceivable way that my app could have silently rejected the call? I don't think that's possible. My interpretation of the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW14) tells me the iPhone OS is in full control and should be able to terminate my app if it wanted.

Am I missing any corner cases here?

Comment: I am having the same problem with my app and many others. It happens when the phone is connected to a slow network (not 3G) and my app is downloading stuff. When the download completes then the phone is able to receive incoming calls! This sounds to me like a very serious OS network problem (iPhone OS 3.1.3).

Comment: @Panagiotis The app in this question doesn't do any data transfer, and the client in question was never able to reproduce.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no programmatic way to do it.

However if you're testing on an EDGE network, Jeff Kelley's answer is correct.

Comment: LOL! We're all in Canada, so just substitute Fido or Rogers or TELUS or Bell and that still stands! :)

Answer (score 7):

Are they on EDGE? While using EDGE, you can't receive calls. They share the same radio.

Comment: Do you have more information about that? Although that's not an issue, as my app does not do any data transmission.

Comment: I was under the impression that EDGE would give your iPhone priority and that your EDGE usages would be halted when a call came in.  I didn't think that the actual ringing of the phone would use EDGE, but that after the call was established, the EDGE bandwidth would be taken up by the phone call.

Comment: I would have bet pretty much anything that you were wrong, and was about to vote you down.  However, that link you provided, the last sentence, well, holy crap.  You are absolutely right, and I can't believe that's how it works.  Sheesh.   I wonder if I've missed any business because of that?  I'm actually pretty irritated at Apple and AT&T.

Answer (score 3):

You're right. There's no way for an application to stop a call from coming in.

The only thing your application can do is be notified that you're getting shutdown because a call is coming in, as the link you provided describes.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar problem a while ago, but it "disappeared" before I could really dig into it.

What *seemed* to be happening:

- My App was doing some heavy calculations in a very tight loop.
- The upper half of the "call incoming" interrupt was handled.
- The bottom half was called "to late".
- The call was dropped.

This has in no way been confirmed by apple or any other developer.
The phone I was working on was ... slightly modified, so it might have been totally our fault.

The loop has since been removed and the problem never showed up again.